# Cannot run mysql commands with Ansible community.mysql

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to run a simple ansible playbook to query a database. Version info:
ansible 2.6.20
Python 3.6

```
# database_query.yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    host_name: "mydbserver"
    database_name: "serverdb"
    database_port: "5501"
    database_user: "sql_svc"
    database_password: "Test1234"
  tasks:
    - name: Simple select query to db
      community.mysql.mysql_query:
        login_host: "{{ host_name }}"
        login_db: "{{ database_name }}"
        login_port: "{{ database_port }}"
        login_user: "{{ database_user }}"
        login_password: "{{ database_password }}"
        query: 
        - SELECT * FROM DECOM_QUEUE
        single_transaction: true
```

My inventory file:

```
[vars]
host_name=mydb.localdomain
database_name=serverdb
database_port=5501
database_user=sql_svc
database_password=Test1234
```

And the command I'm running is:

```
ansible-playbook /usr/local/src/database_query.yml -i /usr/local/src/inventory -vvv
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
ERROR! 'community.mysql.mysql_query' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to have been in '/usr/local/src/database_query.yaml': line 3, column 5, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
  - name: Simple select query to db
    ^ here
```

What gives?

Comment: What you are displaying here is a task, you do indeed need a playbook around this. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_intro.html

Comment: With your edit, your current error cannot be the one you are getting anymore.

Comment: I have also run your current revision and it doesnt yeild the error you show. Check your file for any formating issues, remember yaml is sensitive to spacing, so check if you are using spaces or tabs and not mixing up the format.

Answer (score 0):

Lesson to anyone who comes across this in the future. If your DBA tells you that the target is a "mysql" database, ask them if they are sure it isn't a mssql database. That was the problem.